# apache server with mod_wsgi + python as backend, how can i be able to notified my connection status?

Tags: python, apache, webserver, mod-wsgi

i'm trying to build a web server using apache as the http server, mod_wsgi + python as the logic handler, the server was supposed to handler long request without returning, meaning i want to keep writing stuff into this request.
the problem is, when the link is broken, the socket is in a CLOSE_WAIT status, apache will NOT notify my python program, which means, i have to write something to get an exception, says the link is broken, but those messages were lost and can't be restored.

i tried to get the socket status before writing through /proc/net/tcp, but it could not prevent a quick connect/break connection.

anybody has any ideas, please help, very much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. It is a limitation of the API defined by the WSGI specification. So, nothing to do with Apache or mod_wsgi really as you will have the same issue with any WSGI server if you follow the WSGI specification.

If you search through the mod_wsgi mailing list on Google Groups you will find a number of discussions about this sort of problem in the past.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, and is there any solutions or workarounds i can take without writing my own socket server?  BTW, does apache + php solve this problem?

Comment: I don't believe PHP supports this either. This is because irrespective of the language, it is just hard to do in Apache at all. Consider looking at Tornado instead as it likely has the eventing capabilities for detecting closure of connection.

Comment: i did the exp, php loses information as well... i'm looking right into Tornado write now, and is there any open source socket server i can look on? oh, thank you again :-)